# iOS Simulator: black screen/'Application is expected to have a root view controller'

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

My application was working fine on the Simulator yesterday, today not so much. It shows a black screen consistently, however it deploys and runs fine on device. I've tried so far: resetting the Simulator content and settings, clearing derived data, clean building, ensuring that the Main storyboard is set as the Main user interface, restoring from git to a *much* earlier build in case something else had broken, restarting both Xcode and Simulator.

Is there something I've missed?

Comment: Message seems clear. You haven't set the main window's root view controller.

Comment: Except I have, and it works on device but it doesn't work on Simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to fix it I had to go into `General` for the target, remove the reference for my Storyboard from `Main Interface`, build it and run it, and then read the reference. I'm assuming that something was broken in the build process which running a `Clean` didn't fix.